# class constructor and member variables(fields)

Tags: class, variables, constructor, kotlin

I am trying to declare class with constructor however there seems to be conflict with that syntax and declaring class members.

Any suggestions how these go together?

```
class Person (aName:String) {
    var name : String
        get() = this.name
        set(myName) {this.name = myName}

    init {
        this.name = aName
    }
}
```

Comment: couldn't you just declare name as var?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the setter inside your setter by doing `set(myName) {this.name = myName}`. This is a recursive call and not what you should do. Instead use the [`field` accessor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) like this:

```
name: String? = null
  set(myName) {
     field = myName
  }
```

But actually, you don't even need this. You can declare in the primary constructor, that `name` should be a property of your class:

```
class Person(var name: String)
```

Comment: Why did you make name Optional in the first example?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any of that. You can just define `name` in the constructor as a `var`, and Kotlin will expose it as a property.

```
class Person(var name: String)

// Usage...
val p = Person("Dave")
println(p.name) // "Dave"
p.name = "Phil"
println(p.name) // "Phil"
```

Comment: Yes, I am quite confused with visibility, getters and setters. Compared to java rules you address the members directly and yet there are setters and getters and that makes member visibility even  more confusing to me

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what have been said by others, here is a better syntax if you want to have `aName` as a separate constructor parameter:

```
class Person (aName:String) {
    var name = aName
}
```